# Functional series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{kx}} \cdot \ln{\frac{2x + k}{x + k}}}$$

for convergence on sets $E1 = (0, 1)$ and $E2 = (1, +\infty)$.

1. Explore the pointwise convergence, fix $$x_0$$

By D'Alembert, consider the ratio of members $$a_{n+1} / a_n$$,it equals to $$-\sqrt{\frac{k}{k + 1}} \cdot ln{\frac{x_0}{(x_0 + k) \cdot (x_0 + k + 1)}}$$

the first multiplier is less than one, the second is also => the product is less than 1, and the number series converges on the Dalamber basis, so the original func series converges

2. prove the absence of uniform convergence on the set $E2 = (1, +\infty)$. Take the sequence $$x_n = k, m = N, n = 2N$$ to negate the Cauchy condition.
   We got $$\sum_{k=N + 1}^{2N}{\frac{1}{k} \cdot \ln{\frac{3}{2}}} \ge \sum_{k=N+1}^{2N}{\frac{1}{2N} \cdot \ln{\frac{3}{2}}} \ge \frac{1}{2N} \cdot ln{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot \sum_{k = N + 1}^{2N} 1 = ln{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = epsilon$$

selected eps for which the Cauchy criterion is incorrect => the series does not converge uniformly.

3. What can we do to prove that given series converges/diverges on set E1 and am I correct in my solution about set E2?

Comment: 1) "Dalamber" is d'Alembert. 2) $a_{n+1}/a_n\ne-\sqrt{\frac{k}{k + 1}} \ln{\frac{x_0}{(x_0 + k) \cdot (x_0 + k + 1)}}.$ 3) $a_{n+1}/a_n<1\not\Rightarrow$ the series converges. 4) Your point 2 does not make sense (in particular $x_n=k$: you probably meant $x=k$ but anyway $x$ must be fixed).

Answer (score 1):

In your argument for part (2), $x_N$ cannot depend on the summation index $k$ in the negation of the uniform Cauchy condition.

To prove non-uniform convergence of the series on $(1,\infty)$, we must show that the uniform Cauchy condition is violated in that there exists $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$  there are positive integers  $m > n \geqslant N$ and $x_N \in (1,\infty)$ (note dependence here only on $N$) for which

$$|S_m(x_N)-S_n(x_N)| = \sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{1}{\sqrt{kx_N}} \cdot \ln{\frac{2x_N + k}{x_N + k}} \geqslant \epsilon_0$$

Taking $n = N$, $m = 2N$ and $X_N = N$, we have

$$|S_{2N}(x_N) - S_N(x_N)| = \sum_{k=N+1}^{2N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{kN}} \cdot \ln{\frac{2N + k}{N + k}} \geqslant N \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2N\cdot N}}\cdot \min_{N+1 \leqslant k \leqslant 2N}\ln \frac{2+ \frac{k}{N}}{1 + \frac{k}{N}}$$

Since $x \mapsto \ln \frac{2+x}{1+x}$ is decreasing for all $x >1$ it follows that

$$\min_{N+1 \leqslant k \leqslant 2N}\ln \frac{2+ \frac{k}{N}}{1 + \frac{k}{N}}= \ln \frac{2 + \frac{2N}{N}}{1 + \frac{2N}{N}}=\ln \frac{4}{3},$$

Thus,

$$|S_{2N}(x_N) - S_N(x_N)| \geqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ln \frac{4}{3}:= \epsilon_0$$

and the uniform Cauchy condition is violated.

**Pointwise Convergence and Uniform Convergence on $(0,1)$**

Note that for all $x > 0$

$$\tag{1}0\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{kx}} \ln{\frac{2x + k}{x + k}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{kx}} \ln{\frac{1+ \frac{2x}{k}}{1 + \frac{x}{k}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{kx}} \left[\ln\left(1 + \frac{2x}{k}\right) - \ln\left(1 + \frac{x}{k}\right)\right]$$

Applying the well-known inequality $\frac{y}{1+y} \leqslant \ln(1+y) \leqslant y$ we have

$$\ln\left(1 + \frac{2x}{k}\right) \leqslant \frac{2x}{k}, \quad   \ln\left(1 + \frac{x}{k}\right)\geqslant \frac{\frac{x}{k}}{1 + \frac{x}{k}}= \frac{x}{k+x},$$

and using this to bound terms on the RHS of (1) we get

$$\tag{2}0\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{kx}} \ln{\frac{2x + k}{x + k}} \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{kx}} \left[ \frac{2x}{k} -  \frac{x}{k+x}\right]= \frac{1}{\sqrt{kx}} \frac{kx+ 2x^2}{k(k+x)}= \frac{k\sqrt{x} + 2 x^{3/2}}{k^{3/2}(k+x)}$$

For any fixed $x> 0$, the RHS is $\mathcal{O}(k^{-3/2})$ and the series is pointwise convergent by comparison with the convergent p-series $\sum k^{-3/2}$.

Can you finish now by showing the series is uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$ or any bounded interval $(0,c]$ using the inequality (2) and the Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: thanks! could you give me a hint what to do on the first set (0, 1)? I guess because of the logarithm we can't give it an upper estimate so I don't understand how to prove that on E1(0, 1) set the series converges. And it's not that obvious on E1 how to get a sequence to violate Cauchy condition

Comment: @ivanchai: I added to show you how to bound the general term and show it Is $\mathcal{O}(k^{-3/2}$ for any fixed $x > 0$ to get pointwise convergence.  Then I suggest you finish by showing uniform convergence on $(0,1)$.